# How to copy files to remote server with a user without privileges?

Tags: unix, ssh, scp

When I need to copy a file from local server (server A) to remote server(server B) via SSH, using a user with enough privileges, I do this successfuly like below

```
localpath='/this/is/local/path/file1.txt'
remotepath='/this/is/remote/path/'
mypass='MyPassword123'

sshpass -p $mypass scp username@hostname:$localpath $remotepath
```

Now, I have to transfer a file from server A to server C with a user that doesn't have enough privileges to copy. Then once 
I connected to Server C, I need to send `su` in order to be able to send commands like `cd`, `ls`, etc.

Manually, I access the server C via SSH like this:

```
[root@ServerA ~]# ssh username@hostname
You are trying to access a restricted zone. Only Authorized Users allowed.
Password: 
Last login: Sat Jun 13 10:17:40 2020 from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

ServerC ~ $ 
ServerC ~ $ su
Password:
ServerC /home/myuser # 
ServerC /home/myuser # cd /documents/backups/
ServerC /documents/backups #
```

At this moment `myuser` has superuser privileges and I can send commands.

Then, how can I automate the task to copy files from server A to server C with the need to send `su` once I'm connected to Server C?

I've tried so far doing like this:

```
sshpass -p $mypass ssh -t username@hostname "su -c \"cd /documents/backups/ && ls\""
```

it requests password for `su` and I'm able to send `cd` and `ls` but with this command, I'm not copying files from Server A to Server C, only semi-automating the access to Server C and sending the `su` in Server C.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

```
# $TAR | ssh $username@$hostname "$COMMAND"
+ tar -cv -C /this/is/local/path/file1.txt .
+ ssh username@X.X.X.X 'set -x; rm -f /tmp/copy && mknod /tmp/copy p; su - <<< "su_password
 set -x; tar -xv -C /this/is/remote/path/ . < /tmp/copy" & cat > /tmp/copy'
tar: /this/is/local/path/file1.txt: Cannot chdir: Not a directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
You are trying to access a restricted zone. Only Authorized Users allowed.
Password:
+ rm -f /tmp/copy
+ mknod /tmp/copy p
+ su -
+ cat
Password:
```

Comment: I think you will need to setup that new user on the remote server to have the needed privileges!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue is that currently I'm not able to change privileges or create a new user with that permissions. Is there another way?

Comment: Is the server on any of the cloud platforms, if so then you could create a role with the right permissions to that server and add that user to that role but of course if you can do this then you aught to be able to do the other...

Answer (score 1):

Editorial note: the previous version of this answer used `sudo`, the current version uses `su` as requested in the question.

---

You could use `tar` and pipes, like so:

```
TAR="tar -cv -C $localpath ."
UNTAR="tar -xv -C $remotepath ."
PREPARE_PIPE="rm -f /tmp/copy && mknod /tmp/copy p"
NEWLINE=$'\n' # that's the easiest way to get a literal newline
ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpasswordverydangerous
COMMAND="set -x; $PREPARE_PIPE; su - <<< \"${ROOT_PASSWORD}${NEWLINE} set -x; $UNTAR < /tmp/copy\" & cat > /tmp/copy"
$TAR | ssh username@hostname "$COMMAND"
```

Explanation:

`tar -c .` archives the current directory into a single file. We aren't passing `-f` to `tar`, so that single file is standard output.

`tar -x .` extracts the content of a single tar archive file to the current directory. We aren't passing `-f` to `tar`, so that single file is standard input.

`-C <path>` tells `tar` to `cd` into `<path>` so that it will be the current directory in which files are copied from/to.

`-v` just tells tar to list the files tar archives/extracts, for debugging purposes.

Likewise, `set -x` is just to have `bash` to emit trace information, for debugging purposes.

So we're archiving `$localpath` into stdout, and piping it to `ssh`, which will pipe it to `$COMMAND`.

If there was a way to give `su` the password in the command line, we would have used something like:

```
$TAR | ssh ... su --password ${ROOT_PASSWORD} -c "$UNTAR"
```

and things would have been simple.

But `su` doesn't have that. [`su` runs like a shell, reading from stdin](https://askubuntu.com/a/881237). So it will first read the password, and once the password is read and `su` has established a root session, it reads commands from stdin. That's why we have `su - <<< \"${ROOT_PASSWORD}${NEWLINE}${UNTAR}`.

But now stdin is used by the password and command, so we can't use it as the archive. We could use another file descriptor, but I prefer not to, because then the solution can be more easily ported to work with `sudo` instead of `su`. `sudo` closes all file descriptors, and `sudo -C 200` (only close file descriptors above 200) may not work (didn't work on my test machine).

if we went that direction, we would have used something like

```
$TAR | ssh ... 'exec 9<&2 && sudo -S <<< $mypass bash -c "$UNTAR <&9"'
```

Our next option is to do something like `cat > /tmp/archive.tar` in order to write the entire archive into a file, and then have something like `$UNTAR < /tmp/archive.tar`. But the archive may be huge and we may run out of disk space.

So the idea is to create a dedicated pipe - that's `PREPARE_PIPE`. Pipes don't save anything to disk, and don't store the entire stream in memory, so the reader and the writer have to work concurrently (you know, like with a real pipe).

So having redirected `su`'s stdin from `$ROOT_PASSWORD`, we pull `ssh`'s stdin into our pipe with `cat > /tmp/copy`, and in parallel (`&`) having `$UNTAR` read from the pipe (`< /tmp/copy`).

Notes:

- You could also pass `-z` to both `tar` commands to pass it compressed, if your network is too slow.
- `tar` will preserve the source's metadata, e.g. timestamps and ownership.
- Passing `$ROOT_PASSWORD` to commands is not good practice, anyone who runs `ps -ef` can see the password. There are [ways to pass the password to server C in a more secure way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226638), I didn't include it in order to not further complicate this answer.
- I would suggest asking the server's owner to install `sudo`, so that if the password is compromised via `ps -ef`, at least it's not the root password.

Comment: I'd like to try your solution but in remote server there is no `sudo` and the user doesn't have privileges to install  `sudo` after switching to `su`. Is there a way, at least only to connect via ssh to the remote server and automatically enter the `su` password when prompt appears?

Comment: If it doesn't have privileges then it doesn't have superuser privileges, so I'm not sure what will work. But I found a way to do it with `su`, see edited answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've tried and I get the error below `UPDATE` in original post. Which would be `$ROOT_PASSWORD`? the `su` password or password I use firstly to connect via SSH? If this is the `su` password, how to enter automatically the ssh_password when appears the prompt? using `sshpass`? If it is too complex, is there a way only, to connect via SSH sending automatically the `ssh password` and `su password` without copying any file? only logging.

Comment: if you run `su` on server C to become root, you need to enter the root password, whatever it is. you can't pass it over ssh along with the tar archive, you have to pass it the way I showed in my answer, or try the link at the bottom of my answer

Comment: I stored  `su password` in `$ROOT_PASSWORD` variable. So I did it correct. I see error since localpath it is a file, not a directory. But as I ask in previous comment, If it is too complex using only `su` and not root nor sudo, is there a way to only connect via SSH sending automatically the `ssh password` and `su password` without copying any file? only logging

Comment: There's probably a workaround to do that, I'd open a separate Stack Overflow question for it.

Comment: I asked and no answers yet here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593065/how-to-send-su-password-automatically?noredirect=1#comment1106400_593065